# GUI Monero Balance: 0

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, balance

My Monero GUI shows a balance of 0, despite someone having sent me an amount >0 (I confirmed the transaction on https://xmrchain.net/). I rescanned the wallet cache to no avail. Anyone have any idea how I can get the GUI to show a positive balance?

Comment: Please use ^ guide to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fully sync'd?
You could connect the GUI wallet to a remote node.